# Dell OpenManage Web Interface Inaccessible

Tags: dell, drac, dell-openmanage, dell-poweredge

We've installed all the `Dell` server admin tools on our `Ubuntu 12.04 Server` box using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install srvadmin-all
```

All the `omreport` commands etc work as expected but we need to be able to access the OpenManage web interface, however, it isn't starting up for some reason.

```
# sudo service dsm_om_connsvc start
Starting DSM SA Connection Service:  *

# sudo service dsm_om_connsvc status
dsm_om_connsvcd is stopped
```

As you can see it hasn't started. If I check the log, I see the following errors:

```
# tail -n 100 /opt/dell/srvadmin/var/log/openmanage/dsm_om_connsvcdIO.log

status(-3) 43:44 2014] (2035) RunServer:daemon worker forked
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) RunServer:worker process entry
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2035) RunServer:daemon waiting for worker init status
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) ModuleAttach: entry 0
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) ModuleAttach: starting the startserver thread
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) ModuleAttach(ERROR): startserver thread exited prematurely,     aborting!
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) ModuleAttach: exit with errors!
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) RunServer: ModuleAttach failed
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) RunServer:worker process EXIT status(-3)
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2036) RunServer exit with status(-3)
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2035) RunServer:daemon process EXIT status(-3)
[Nov  4 09:43:44 2014] (2034) RunServer:parent process EXIT status(-3)
```

I found a post online that said:

```
Never mind. I just noticed that there was an upgrade available for
srvadmin-jre. After upgrade to srvadmin-jre 7.4.0-1 I was able to start
dsm_om_connsvc.
```

But I seem to have this version already:

```
# dpkg -l | grep "srvadmin-jre"
ii  srvadmin-jre           7.4.0-1            Oracle Java Runtime Environment
```

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: Don't think we did unfortunately :( I moved on to a different company so not sure if they've since resolved it.

Comment: Also searching for a solution.